the alternative to the clause 'not just that S+V but that S+V'?
(A) is grammatically correct. But how about (B) and (C)?
Is it a must to keep that after but in accordance with parallelism?
And how about just omitting the first that?


(A) She said not just that he was rich but that he was healthy.
(B) She said not just that he was rich but he was healthy.
(C) She said not just he was rich but that he was healthy.



I could live with B, as that is often elided/assumed/optional as a connector. But C is a bridge too far.

Syntactically, "relativizer" that is always optional in such contexts, so it's just a matter of opinion whether you like any particular permutation of present or deleted relativizers. But C is pretty ugly, as @YosefBaskin points out (we usually delete subsequent instances of optional elements, not the first one).

Could you replace 'not just that S+V but that S+V' with a sample sentence in English, please?
Either way, what could 'not just that S+V but that S+V' mean in English, logic, maths or any other language?

(A) might be OK, but the others are really awkward. How about this?

She said he was not only rich, but also healthy.


I had upvoted swmcdonnell but now I notice that though It’s correct, ’She said he was not only rich, but also healthy’ doesn’t address the issue at all; it simply sidesteps the subject, rendering the Question redundant. ’She said he was not only rich, but also healthy’ changes the structure beyond useful comparison, for no inherent benefit. I think cmw falls behind the same smokescreen.

The entire thing is awkward, so I don't think the examples make it clear exactly what the question is. You probably wouldn't say any of the three examples, so it's kind of hard to create a proper answer.

I, for one, wholly support that!
